# Adding image outside of project C# Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, fileopenpicker

In my xaml file I have an image named OutputImg. 
I also have a textblock named OutputTB for displaying the name of the image and a button which lets me choose an image from my Pictures folder.

Code behind :

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = Picker.ViewMode.List;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicutresLiibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    StorageFile.file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    OutputTB.text = file.Name;


    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.path));
    OutputImg.Source = image;
}
```

Question is that even though I dont get any errors, my picture won't show. It writes out the picture's name to OutputTB.text but Image just stays empty. How can I make my selected image appear in the OutputImg image box.

I understand that there might be a really basic thing I'm missing here but its just meant to be a learning project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `file.path` to create the `Uri` object for the bitmap because `file.path` gives the old style path (e.g. `c:\users\...\foo.png`). The bitmap expects the new style uri path (e.g. `ms-appdata:///local/path..to..file.../foo.png`).

However, as far as I know there isn't any way to specify the new style uri path for the Pictures Library. Therefore, you have to use a simple workaround:

Since you have a reference to the file, you can instead get access to the file's stream, and then set the stream as the bitmap's source:

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
OutputTB.text = file.Name;

// Open a stream for the selected file.
var fileStream =
    await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

// Set the image source to the selected bitmap.
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(fileStream);

OutputImg.Source = image;
```